# Let $G$ be a group of order $p^2$q, where $p$, $q$ are primes such that $p<q$ and $p \ne p+1$, such that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ of order $q$

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

> Let $G$ be a group of order $p^2q$, where $p$, $q$ are primes such that $p<q$ and $q \ne p+1$, such that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ of order $p^2$. Show that $G$ is abelian.

I consider $Z(G)$, since $Z(G)$ is subgroup of $G$, then $|Z(G)|$ can be either $1$, $p$, $q$, $pq$, $p^2$ or $p^2q$

If $|Z(G)|=p^2q$, then $G=Z(G)$, thus $G$ is abelian.

If $|Z(G)|=p$ or $|Z(G)|=q$, then $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, thus $G$ is abelian

Now I don't what to do when $|Z(G)|=p^2, pq, 1 $

I don't know if there is another way

Comment: Do you know the class equation? That will help you take care of the $|Z(G)|=1$ case.

Comment: Is $|G|=p^2q^2$?

Comment: Where is  $q$  used in the question ?

Comment: What did you **actually** mean to write? Because requiring that $\;p\neq p+1\;$ seems to be a typo or a rather weak requirement...

Comment: What is the order of $G$??

Comment: q is different to p+1 and the order of G is $p^2$q

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $|Z(G)|=p$, then $|G/Z(G)|=\frac{|G|}{|Z(G)|}=pq$, so it isn't so straightforward that it's cyclic. Same for $|Z(G)|=q$; $G/Z(G)$ may be cyclic or not.

But your logic actually applies if $|Z(G)|=p^2$ or $|Z(G)|=pq$.

---

I will only sketch out the proof, you should fill in the details.

If you have $|Z(G)|=p$, then $G/Z(G)\simeq\Bbb{Z}_p\times\Bbb{Z}_q$, which is abelian (you can prove it's actually cyclic, and only then you initial assertion that $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic in this case holds true). Since the elements of $Z(G)$ commute with every element of $G$, it follows that $G$ is abelian.

The same happens when $|Z(G)|=q$, but in this case $G/Z(G)\simeq \Bbb{Z}_p\times\Bbb{Z}_p$ or $G/Z(G)\simeq \Bbb{Z}_{p^2}$.

Finally, if $|Z(G)|=1$, then $Z(G)={1_G}$, that is, the neutral element of $G$. Thus $Z(G)$ is a subgroup of $H$. If you apply the Class Equation to $H$ (using conjugation as action of $H$ to itself), you'll arrive at a contradiction.

Comment: True, I had forgotten that $p,q$ were prime when typing that. Thanks, it should be better now (also included that observation in the second part as well).